# Set Expiration on MySQL Table Data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a MySQL Database I am building, I have a column where there is a simple 0 or 1 (true or false) data field. All data is initially set to 0.  If a user presses a button on the website I am building, it will change (in the database) from 0 to 1 to show the user as Logged in.  I want them to be *automatically* Logged out by the end of the day (Again, this is accomplished by setting them to 0).

Here is the question:  Is there a way to "expire" data after a period of time and set it back to default (or 0)? If so, can it be based on a specific period of time?

If there is any SQL command or method to do this, what about PHP?

Comment: mysql has some task scheduling capabilities. php does not. but you can use system schedulers (e.g. unix cron) to run php scripts at specified times.

Comment: I think you answered my question, this is the ideal way in the first place, "run php scripts at specified times." Can you tell me more about that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without triggering a procedure you may be out of luck here. However, why don't you do the following: instead of a Boolean use a date and set the date on login. Then, instead of asking if login is true, ask if the login date is the current date. No expiration cleanup necessary, problem solved.

Comment: You have a great point there... will mark you correct. I was over thinking this.

Comment: Since now you are no longer limited by a single trigger per day you could also change that condition to an interval less than 24 hours.

Comment: In the column that was only for 0 or 1's, I am now using the date of the day (PHP: `date('d');`)  So today is January 11th, the data entered would be 11.  Only those marked as "on duty" will be associated with TODAY's date.  I am going to addd one more check.  `If the day entered does not match today, reset it to 0`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the events (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) or crontab ( only linux/unix)